# If statement expected an identifier?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and this is probably a very simple question but I don't understand it..

```
if (choice >= 0 && <= 0.33)
{
    choice = "1";
}

else if (choice >= 0.34 && <= 0.66)

{
    choice = "2";
}

else 

{
    choice = "3";
}
```

Why doesn't the line if (choice >= 0 && <= 0.33) work? Doesn't it create an if statement for a number that is in between 0 and 0.33 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the variable on each comparison, like:

```
if (choice >= 0 && choice <= 0.33)
```

So a full example:

```
if (choice >= 0 && choice <= 0.33) {
    choice = "1";
} else if (choice >= 0.34 && choice <= 0.66) {
    choice = "2";
} else {
    choice = "3";
}
```

Comment: In oher words, OP's version is parsed as `if ((choice >= 0) && (<= 0.33))`, and 0.33 has nothing to be compared against.

Answer (score 0):

you want

```
else if (choice >= 0.34 && choice <= 0.66)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough when you only once use the `choice`. You need to specify it all the time you want to compare it.

```
if (choice >= 0 && choice <= 0.33) {
    choice = "1";
} else if (choice >= 0.34 && choice <= 0.66) {
    choice = "2";
} else {
    choice = "3";
}
```